# Lexer negation in ANTLR - why doesn't double-negation work?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have this token I would like to match any string of non-special characters except for the literal string "TODAY".

ANTLR makes this a pain in the butt:

```
UNQUOTED        :
  ( ~('T'|'t'|~UnquotedStartChar) UnquotedChar*
    ( ~('O'|'o'|~UnquotedChar) UnquotedChar*
    | ('O'|'o')
      ( ~('D'|'d'|~UnquotedChar) UnquotedChar*
      | ('D'|'d')
        ( ~('A'|'a'|~UnquotedChar) UnquotedChar*
        | ('A'|'a')
          ( ~('Y'|'y'|~UnquotedChar) UnquotedChar*
          )?
        )?
      )?
    )?
  )
  ;
```

I figured I was being clever by double-negating in the `~('T'|'t'|~UnquotedStartChar)` - it should match everything that isn't 'T', 't', or non-permitted in the start char normally... which intuitively seems like it should work, and when I think about it a bit, seems like it should work, but when I actually try to compile it, I get this error message:

```
error(100): antlr/QueryParser.g:0:1: syntax error: buildnfa: MismatchedTreeNodeException(16!=32)
```

`UnquotedStartChar` is, in itself, quite a mess... but I'm not entirely sure it's relevant yet. Here's the first couple of levels anyway.

```
fragment
UnquotedStartChar
  : EscapeSequence
  | ~( ProhibitedAtStartOfUnquoted )
  ;

fragment
ProhibitedAtStartOfUnquoted
  : ProhibitedInUnquoted
  | Slash | PLUS | MINUS | DOLLAR;

fragment
EscapeSequence
  : Backslash
    ( 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    | ~( 'u' )
    )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In lexer grammar, rule (token) that is defined earlier takes precedence in case of a conflict, so you could just define a token for 'TODAY' above `UNQUOTED` and it should match the string instead of the general `UNQUOTED` token.

Comment: Ah, that's true, maybe my example was bad. There are other cases where I couldn't get that to work sensibly. For instance, I also have a "W/" token where a digit could be following it like "w/3". I can make the whole thing a single token, but then I'd have to parse the number back out of it. So I tried just having a "W/" token, but then "w/3" still became UNQUOTED.

Comment: Ah OK, I was afraid you were trying to achieve something that could be done an easier way.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like even the dodgy lookahead trick we're using in the code now is using it for TODAY when it doesn't have to. >_>  So I'll probably fix that whether or not I can fix the others. Most of our keywords are just declared up the top.